# How to access a button that is not saved by id in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

```
<button class="radius ng-scope"
        ng-click="editSuggestions()"
        ng-if="::canBeEdited()">
  <img ng-srcset="images/button/button_icon_edit_gray.9147b0d4.png 1x, images/button/button_icon_edit_gray_2x.a0d25df9.png 2x"
       src="images/button/button_icon_edit_gray.9147b0d4.png">
  <span>Edit Log</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I am trying ti get the button edit log and click it using selenium.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.className("radius ng-scope")).click();
```

Comment: you tried by xpath ... ("//button[@class='radius ng-scope']").click();

Comment: better rep better help.

Comment: @L.Bar If this answer helped, the OP *should* accept the answer. Reminding new users how the process is supposed to work isn't a bad thing... but it does make me feel a little dirty when I do it... :)

Comment: i am new to Stackoverflow so leme know how do you accept the answer. I ll do that, coz it helped me,

Comment: just click on v near the answer (this will show not only to you and to others that there is a solution for that question @JeffC. )